# android: how can I detect when user touch left 20% of view area?

Tags: android, motionevent, android-touch-event

In an `activity` by using

`public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)`

how can I know an user is **touching** left `Y-axis` of 20% edge area?

It should be generic and orientation handled.
I don't want to create any hidden view on that.

Comment: get x and y of touch and than compare with 20% of screens x and y .

Comment: @DayDayHappy can you show some color on that specific area just to clear that  left 20% of view area?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Get device width
- Calculate left 20% width size (from 0 to X)
- Use  `event.getX()`
- Check that `event.getX()` is inside device with 20%

[image]

example :

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

        private LinearLayout background;
        private float xValue, yValue, leftPersentage;
        private int height,width;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

            DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
            height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
            width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

            leftPersentage = (width)*20/100;

            background = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.background);
            background.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    xValue = event.getX();
                    yValue = event.getY();
                    Log.d("Values Clicked" , xValue +"and" + yValue);
                    if(xValue <= leftPersentage){
                        // perform your task 
                        Log.d("Values Clicked onLeft" , xValue +"and" + yValue);
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the display size then get the point from touch event. Compare it mathematically to know if its left 20% or not.

get display size

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();    
float dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
```

get the touch points.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    float touchedX = ev.getX();
    float touchedY = ev.getY();
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```